# Share code between fragments

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns, android-fragments

I have two ListFragments which needs to share some code. This was very basic by just creating a abstract fragment extending ListFragment and then let my two fragments both extend my abstract fragment.

However, now I need a third fragment to use the code from my abstract fragment. However, this third fragment is not a ListFragment but a GridFragment.

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As java won't support `multiple inheritance` either seperate your generic code in to `Fragment` **Super class** or make static methods.

or

Simply write a `FragmentUtil` class.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you put your shared code in class that dont extends any Fragments. In your fragments classes you make calls to your SharedCode.class .